# how to show audio frequency in waveform?

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es, rendering, waveform

I wanna render wave which shows frequency data of audio.

I have data point of 150 points/second.

I have rendered it using canvas,showing line for each data value. so I show 150 lines for 1 second of song, its showing in right way but when we scroll the view, its lagging.

Is there any Library which can render the data points using openGL, canvas or using any other method which will be smooth while scrolling.

[These are two waves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFTzg.png). Each line represent one data point, with minimum value zero and maximum value will be highest value in data set.

How to render this wave in OpenGL or using any other library because Its lagging in Scrolling if rendered using canvas.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could show an example of how it looks like. How do you create the lines? Are the points scattered? Do you have to connect them or do you have a fixed point?

Usually in OpenGL-ES the process would looks like:
- read in your data of audio
- sort them so that OpenGL knows how to connect them
- upload them to your vertexShader

Comment: I have updated the question with wave. How can i make this wave or smething similar to it, in OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend [this](https://learnopengl.com) tutorial. I don't know your OpenGL background, thus this is a perfect tool to start it. 
Actually, your application shouldn't be too complicated and the tutorial should offer you enough information. In the case, you want to visualize each second with 150 points
Just a small overview

1. Learn how to set up a window with OpenGL
2. You described a 2d application 
   -define x values as eg. -75 to 75 
   -define y values as your data

   - define Lines as x,y dataSet
3. Use to draw

   glBegin(GL_Lines)

   glVertexf((float)x value of each line,(float)y small value of each line);
   glVertexf((float)x value of each line,(float)y high value of each line);

   glEnd();

If you have to use mobile graphics you need shaders because OpenGLES only support shader in GLSL

4. define your OpenGL camera!